# Problem with Linux mint 17.2 boot

Tags: boot-process

I have installed this once already but had problems after loading and formatting a iPod shuffle with Rhythmbox. This mint 17.2 seems to be a lot more compatible with my MacBook Pro than the Ubuntu 13.04, but during the second install I am having problems during boot up. I am getting a black screen.

This is a single boot system. prior to installing mint the first time I formatted my drive. I just ran boot repair but it [indicated that I had a problem (cf. pastebin)](http://paste2.org/w9kfy198). If anyone can help, it would be much appreciated. I am not too familiar with the Linux boot process.

When I loaded it the first time I partitioned the drive in three parts: a boot sector sda1 then sda2 for Linux and the swap sector.

Comment: Apparently it was not able to write grub. I wont be able to help you further today, however will leave the note to others.

Answer (score 0):

```
grub-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/sdb1.
```

It looks as if this is your problem.
Unless /dev/sdb1 is a second hard drive, GRUB has probably tried to install itself to a USB stick. Looking at the logs, it seems as if /dev/sda1 is your EFI system partition.

You might be able to fix this by chrooting into your Linux Mint partition from a live system by running these commands as root from a liveusb / cd:

```
mkdir /mnt/chroot
mount /dev/(sdaX) /mnt/chroot (where sdaX is your linux mint root partition)
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/chroot/boot
mount /dev/(sdaX) /mnt/chroot/home (Where sdaX is your home partition. If you don't have one, omit this command)
```

then execute:

```
cd /mnt/chroot
mount -t proc proc proc/
mount --rbind /sys sys/
mount --rbind /dev dev/
chroot /mnt/chroot /bin/bash
```

this will chroot into your existing Linux Mint installation.

running something like:

```
grub-install --recheck /dev/sdx
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

For a BIOS system, or

```
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=$esp --bootloader-id=grub --recheck
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

For an EFI system, where $esp is your boot partition (sda1) should reinstall and configure grub correctly.

Comment: Thank you. I will try that now. By chrooting, you mean using a live USB and executing those commands as sudo?

Comment: Sorry for the ignorance but I'm not an expert with this sort of thing. In your first line you referenced sdb1 from the grub probe. However in your last statement you suggest replacing sda1 in the command? Also it looks like the same command 2 times. Is that correct?

Comment: my fault, i'll edit the response :)